# Is Django many to many really necessary?

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have been learning to use Django over the last year and Python is not my native programming language.   Normally, when I want to create a many to many relationship, I would create 3 tables, one of which contained two foreign keys to each of the other two tables.   For this reason, I find the Django manytomany field very unnatural.   Does this many to many field create a third table in the database to store the relationship ?   If this is the case, then using a many to many field will stop the class structure from directly representing the table structure.

What I am wondering is if there is a reason I should be using this manytomany field or could I get away with using 3 classes to represent a many to many relationship ?

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I would create 3 tables, one of which contained two foreign keys to each of the other two tables. For this reason, I find the Django manytomany field very unnatural.

This is ***exactly*** what Django is doing behind the curtains. If you inspect the database, you will see a [*junction table* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity). Django simply does this in the background. It simply *presents* it to the foreground as a field. As you can see in the [*database Representation* of the `ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#id1):

> Behind the scenes, Django **creates an intermediary join table to represent the many-to-many relationship**. By default, this table name is generated using the name of the many-to-many field and the name of the table for the model that contains it. Since some databases don’t support table names above a certain length, these table names will be automatically truncated and a uniqueness hash will be used, e.g. `author_books_9cdf`. You can manually provide the name of the join table using the `db_table` option.

You can even add extra fields to this junction table, by defining the model in between explicitly, and specify this in the [**`through=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through). For example:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=128,
        unique=True
    )

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=128,
        unique=True
    )
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(
        Category,
        through='ItemCategory'
        related_name='items'
    )

class ItemCategory(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    validated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

A `ManyToManyField` is thus more a concept to make representing and querying more convenient.

Comment: Thanks for your replay - it has helped with my understanding.   In your example, if you deleted the piece of code saying categories = models.ManyToManyField( .... ), then wouldn't the code still represent a many to many relationship ?   This makes the manytomany field feel a bit surplus to requirements.   I guess to be fair you would have to say that the same applies if you use 3 classes in a situation where only 2 are necessary, but there is a definite loss of clarity as the class structure no longer represents the table structure directly.

Comment: @MarkyMark1000: yes it would still represent a many-to-many relation without the `ManyToManyField`. But then querying for the `categories` of an `Item` might be more cumbersome. The `ManyToManyField` thus adds a "conceptual layer" on top of it, to make it convenient to query with `myitem.categories.all()`.

Comment: Ah, ok, that's interesting, so you are saying that I might find it difficult to query in Django later on if I don't include the ManyToManyField.   That is really useful to know.   Just out of interest, could I also add an 'Items' field to the category table that used the same 'ItemCategory' class ?   The idea would be so that I could also use my category.items.all()

Comment: Thanks, this has been really useful.

Comment: For anyone interested, I found that when I tried to add an items manytomany field, the migrations failed because the Item class didn't exist yet.   I guess the ManyToMany field is one directional and you need to pick which class comes first carefully.